# How to make JPanel use JTabbedPane UI without tabs using Aqua/system LAF?

Tags: java, macos, swing

First off, I have tried [other solutions](http://www.coderanch.com/t/344299/GUI/java/Hide-tabs-JTabbedPane). Unfortunately they rely on you using a cross platform LAF.

A panel in OS X's System preferences:
[image: OS X network preferences]

looks identical to a JTabbedPane:
[image: JTabbedPane]

but without the tabs. I am trying to make something that feels native, but I can't find any other components with this UI, and I can't figure out how to hack a JTabbedPane so it displays normally just without tabs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how to hack a JTabbedPane so it displays normally just without tabs.

I assume you are trying to display multiple panels in the same space. If so, then you can use a `CardLayout`. You can swap panels by specifying the name of the panel to display in the `CardLayout`.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: This doesn't help. I'm not trying to actually use a tabbed pane for it's functionality, but solely for its UI. I only have one panel that I am trying to display, I just want it to look like the panel in system preferences. I tested card layout and it unfortunately does not look  recessed.

Comment: @user3236716 You mean you want the light gray panel and border?

Comment: `I tested card layout and it unfortunately does not look recessed.` - I don't use OSX so I'm not sure what the LAF looks like, but you can always add a Border to the CardLayout panel to give it a recessed effect. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Borders` you can check out.

Comment: @camickr Borders are changed with a LAF unfortunately, and do not appear native on any OS. I realize that what I am doing might be considered too perfectionist to matter, I was just hoping there was a way to do it. I simply can't pull off the effect myself with a custom paintComponent().

Comment: `Borders are changed with a LAF unfortunately,` - not on a panel. A panel doesn't have a default Border, so you can specify whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant to say aren't. I'm trying to get the specific look that seems to only be created by com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneContrastUI and nothing in the border class will produce anything remotely native looking.

Comment: @user3236716 All I am seeing in the photo, is two colors, one for the panel and one for the Border. Sounds to me like a simple LineBorder will work. If you are not sure about the color to make the LineBorder, the maybe the [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) can help. It will display the various properties used by each component. Or you can always create a custom Border, that matches exactly what you want which would be far easier the trying to change the UI of a tabbed pane.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94779/discussion-between-user3236716-and-camickr).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just working on my paintComponent method, and I think this makes it look pretty accurate:

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(new Color(212, 212, 212));
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), 10, 10);
        g2.setColor(new Color(223, 223, 223));
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 1, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()-1, 10, 10);
        g2.setColor(new Color(227, 227, 227));
        g2.fillRoundRect(1, 1, this.getWidth()-2, this.getHeight()-2, 10, 10);
    }
```

I think it could be optimized a bit by changing fill() to draw() but this gets the job done. Unfortunately it won't look great on other operating systems, so I will have to handle those separately.

Edit: matched colors using Photoshop.